# Error callback OAuth2.0 with Spreadsheet v4

Tags: javascript, sql-server, jsp, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0

I am trying solve a problem that I have with my web services.
I have had reading all document about outh2.0 in Java and to integrate Spreadsheet and I have 3 problems.

My web application that I use contains files jsp and Servlet.
I have a form where the user fill fields and then clic the button for submit.
Then it start flow token. 
If first the page call to put email, then if the user Accept or denege access, but them...I do not know controle anything.

1.- The page "callback", how many methods I need? what kind the page need: JSP or html o Servlet? I dont know.
I know that in my api console, I configure (client id, client secret, i can download file json, Authorized JavaScript origins, Authorized redirect URIs ) but i do not know in my code where to see it.
I have in Java this:

public class SheetsQuickstart {

```
/** Application name. */
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Name_APP";

/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), "credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {

    /** Load client secrets. 
     * */
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("\client_secret.json");  

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");

    System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());

    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
 * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {

    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();            
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Sheets service = getSheetsService();

    // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
    String spreadsheetId = "Id spreadsheet";
    String range = "A4:C6";
    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
        .get(spreadsheetId, range)
        .execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Name, Major");
      for (List<?> row : values) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2));
      }
    }
}
```

}

I have my file json and it is OK.
I do not see where I need to see access_toke or how I can get it.

Someone have any example with this or can help me please?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Here put my code.

public class ServletOAuth2Callback extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static String GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "";
public static String GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "";


public ServletOAuth2Callback() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    String stateP = request.getParameter("state");
    System.out.println("stateP --> " +stateP);


    /** No funciona */
    String error = request.getParameter("error");


    if(error != null){

        System.out.println("");
        String volverAJsp = "";
        response.sendRedirect(volverAJsp);
    }

    else{

        System.out.println("El usuario ha aceptado el acceso");
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        System.out.println("code --> " +code);  


        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flujo = null;
        flujo = AutorizacionOAuth2.newFlow();
        System.out.println("Flujo string            --> " +flujo.toString());
        System.out.println("Flujo token encodeurl   --> " +flujo.getTokenServerEncodedUrl());
        System.out.println("Flujo access_type       --> " +flujo.getAccessType()); //ahora mismo es null
        System.out.println("Flujo client_id         --> " +flujo.getClientId());
        System.out.println("Flujo scopes as string  --> " +flujo.getScopesAsString());
        System.out.println("Flujo nuevo token       --> " +flujo.newTokenRequest(code));

        GoogleTokenResponse token = null;
        token = AutorizacionOAuth2.requestAccessToken(flujo, code);
        //System.out.println("Token toString    --> " +token.toString());

        System.out.println("Token access      --> " +token.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("Token expire      --> " +token.getExpiresInSeconds());
        System.out.println("Token type        --> " +token.getTokenType());

        String urlSsSession = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("URL");
        System.out.println("La UrlSsSession   --> " +urlSsSession);

        String idHoja = urlSsSession.substring(39, 83);
        System.out.println("idHoja --> " +idHoja);

        Sheets service = AutorizacionOAuth2.getSheetsService(flujo, token);
        System.out.println("Servicio string --> " +service.toString());
        System.out.println("Servicio name   --> " +service.getApplicationName());
        System.out.println("Servicio sheets --> " +service.spreadsheets().sheets().toString());

        String spreadsheetId = idHoja;
        String range = "A4:C";

        System.out.println("Spreadsheet --> " +spreadsheetId.toString());
        System.out.println("range       --> " +range);

        Get respuesta = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range);

        System.out.println("Get respuesta --> " +respuesta.toString());
        System.out.println("Exe respuesta --> " +respuesta.execute());                      
    }   
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo doPost() en la clase SOAuth2Callback.");

    String urlSpreadsheet = request.getParameter("URL");
    System.out.println("La URL del text --> " +urlSpreadsheet);

    request.getSession().setAttribute("URL", urlSpreadsheet);

    String variable = AutorizacionOAuth2.getOauthUrlGoogle(request, urlSpreadsheet);
    System.out.println("Metodo getOauthUrlGoogle--> " +variable);

    String estado = request.getSession().getId();
    System.out.println("estado --> " +estado);

    response.sendRedirect(variable);    
}
```

public class AutorizacionOAuth2 {

```
private static String CLIENT_ID = "";
private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, SheetsScopes.DRIVE);

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "";

private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY = null;

private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = null; 

private static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static String client_id = "";
private static String client_secret = "";

private static String redirectUrl = "";

private static java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), "credentials/creden_json/");

public static String getCallbackUrl() {

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo getCallbackUrl() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    String redirectUrl = "";

    return redirectUrl;
}


public static GoogleTokenResponse requestAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeFlow flow, String code) throws IOException, GoogleJsonResponseException {

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo requestAccessToken() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    return (GoogleTokenResponse) flow.newTokenRequest(code).setRedirectUri("http://localhost:8080/appweb/ServletOAuth2Callback").execute();
}

public static String getOauthUrlGoogle(HttpServletRequest request, String urlSpreadsheet) {

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo getOauthUrlGooglePrueba() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    StringBuilder oauthUrl = new StringBuilder();
    oauthUrl.append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth")
        .append("?client_id=").append(CLIENT_ID) //the client id from the api console registration
        .append("&response_type=code")
        .append("&scope=").append(SCOPE) //scope is the api permissions we are requesting
        .append("&redirect_uri=").append(redirectUrl) //the servlet that google redirects to after authorization
        .append("&state=").append(request.getSession().getId())//ID de la sesion del usuario
        .append("&urlSpreadsheet=").append(urlSpreadsheet); 

    return oauthUrl.toString();
}

public static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow newFlow() throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    try {

        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } 

    catch (Throwable t) {

        System.out.println("Ha fallado la ruta de DATA_STORE_DIR");
        t.printStackTrace();
        //System.exit(1);
    }

return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
        client_id, client_secret, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setApprovalPrompt("force") 
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
}


public static Sheets getSheetsService(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flujo, GoogleTokenResponse token) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo getSheetsService() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    try{

        GoogleCredential credential = AutorizacionOAuth2.autorizar(flujo);

        credential.setFromTokenResponse(token);
        credential.refreshToken();

        System.out.println("Ya tenemos la credenciales en la variable credential.");

        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();    
    }
    catch(IOException io){
        System.out.println("Estamos en la excepcion");
        io.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}


public static GoogleCredential autorizar(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flujo) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Estamos en el metodo autorizar() en la clase AutorizacionOAuth2.");

    InputStream clientSecretReader = new FileInputStream("");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets
            .load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(clientSecretReader));

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
            .build();

    System.out.println("Credentials guardadas en " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Credenciales --> " +credential.toString());

    return credential;
}
```